# Counting duplicates when using "IN" operator

Tags: sql, sqlite

I think I narrowed my query down to an easy-to-understand example here:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) FROM tableX WHERE prod_id IN 
(SELECT prod_id FROM tableY WHERE val = 7)
```

My issue is this - sometimes the same prod_id will be returned multiple times.  But because of the nature of the "IN" operator, it would only be counted once by the "SUM(cost)" function.  What is the best way to handle this?  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some basic data ? You can write it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7

Comment: Use not `IN` but the `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: you can also apply `distinct` to prod_id in inner query

Comment: (1) Your query doesn't return `prod_id`, so your observation doesn't make sense.  (2) Your query returns exactly one row, so there are no duplicates.  Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1) it makes a lot of sense: imagine one is the transaction list. The other is the product description list. If you sold the product `val = 7` twice you expect the total amount to be accounted twice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 2) the duplicates are in the inner query

Comment: @zerkms . . . `IN` implicitly dedups the results.  In fact, in general, a `WHERE` clause cannot INCREASE the number of rows being processed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that's right, and that's the very subject of the question: they need to `SUM` as many times as the inner query returns the matching value.

Comment: @zerkms . . . I misread the question.  You have the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not verified it, but I don't see a reason why this won't work:

```
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM tableX
INNER JOIN tableY ON tableX.prod_id = tableY.prod_id AND tableY.val = 7
```

Comment: That did it.  It wasn't quite a direct translation to my specific use case (where tableY was a complex set of subqueries)... but it answered the question as asked and pointed me in the right direction for a solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that you just need to group by the product.

```
SELECT prod_id, SUM(cost) AS TotalCost
FROM tableX 
WHERE prod_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT prod_id 
    FROM tableY
    WHERE val = 7
)
GROUP BY prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join instead of `IN` will ensure that each `x` item would be counted as many times as there are records in the `y`:

```
SELECT SUM(cost)
FROM tableX x
JOIN tableY y ON x.prod_id = y.prod_id AND val = 7
```

Note that this approach works only in situations when you don't want to retrieve any other columns from `x`. If that is not the case, you would need to group by on the additional columns that you wish to return:

```
SELECT x.prod_id, x.name, SUM(cost), COUNT(*)
FROM tableX x
JOIN tableY y ON x.prod_id = y.prod_id AND val = 7
GROUP BY x.prod_id, x.name
```